# Jquery resizeable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the alsoResize option.
It works when I write this:

```
$(obj).resizable({ minHeight: 150, minWidth: 280, alsoResize: '.tab_content'});
```

but the problem is that it's resizing all 'tab_content' elements in the page.
I want it to be relative to 'obj' which also contains a 'tab_content',
I tried: `alsoResize: $('.tab_content',obj)`
but it didn't work,
any suggestions,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used resizable before, but I would try something like:

```
$(obj).resizable({ minHeight: 150, minWidth: 280, alsoResize: $(this).children('.tab_content')});
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be

```
var tab_content=$('.tab_content', obj);
console.log(tab_content.length);

//if all is well
$(obj).resizable({minHeight: 150, minWidth: 150, alsoResize:tab_content});
```